# Error in Publishing message to Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-producer-api

I am new to Kafka and try to setup enviroment for it . 
I am trying to run a single node Kafka but I am getting error in that.

Following following steps on mac

```
1. brew install zookeeper
2. brew install kafka
3. zkServer start
4.  kafka-server-start.sh /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
5.bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
6.bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test 
This is a message
```

But I am getting following error. Please let me know , if I missed anything

```
[2015-10-19 15:48:46,632] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2015-10-19 15:48:46,637] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2015-10-19 15:48:46,638] ERROR Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: Failed to fetch topic metadata for topic: test (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2015-10-19 15:48:46,746] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2015-10-19 15:48:46,749] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2015-10-19 15:48:46,749] ERROR Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: Failed to fetch topic metadata for topic: test (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2015-10-19 15:48:46,860] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2015-10-19 15:48:46,863] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2015-10-19 15:48:46,863] ERROR Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: Failed to fetch topic metadata for topic: test (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2015-10-19 15:48:46,973] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2015-10-19 15:48:46,977] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2015-10-19 15:48:46,977] ERROR Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: Failed to fetch topic metadata for topic: test (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2015-10-19 15:48:47,083] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2015-10-19 15:48:47,084] ERROR Failed to send requests for topics test with correlation ids in [0,8] (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2015-10-19 15:48:47,086] ERROR Error in handling batch of 1 events (kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread)
kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3 tries.
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:90)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:105)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:88)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:68)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:547)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:67)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:45)
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alok, This very common issue of port and host. 
Could you please confirm the HOST and PORT for Zookeeper and Kafka Broker. I'm assuming you have configured Kafka in your local so make sure you are providing proper host name.

Run bellow command to make sure the Zookeeper and Kafka Broker running on port which you have mentioned in your command :

> **netstat -a | grep port**

Please let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: Hi, Port seems correct to me. I verified in zoo.cfg and server.properties. I am using localhost in place of hostname.

Comment: can you run command "hostname" on your CLI and verify what is the hostname for your machine.

Answer (score 7):

The problem on my side has been solved by setting the value `localhost` to the following properties inside the `config/server.properties` file:

```
host.name
advertised.host.name
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I will also add the need to setting `advertised.port=yourPortNum`, specially if running on a local machine and the brokers have different ports.

Comment: [these are now deprecated](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation#configuration) you can just remove them in favour of `listeners` or `advertised.listeners`

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the zookeeper with the proper configuration like you do with the kafka:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

You may delete the broker log and then try again:

```
rm -R /tmp/kafka-logs (default location)
```

If you still have problems check the logs.

Comment: I am starting with default configuration . I didnt change zookeeper.properties.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the host.name property in server.properties file. By default it is commented out and points to local machine. So, if you want to start kafka locally, just uncomment this out and you are all set. Meaning - 
host.name=localhost

Answer (score 0):

i had set the localhost to 127.0.0.1 to fix this issue in server.properties

Answer (score 0):

While using Kafka broker, zookeeper is must.
You must start `zookeeper-server` before starting `kafka-server`.

Be very careful with ports, when to use `zookeeper port`, when to use `kafka broker port`

If you are getting any exception related to Metadata, Check if your topic exist in broker.

`./kafka-topics.sh  --zookeeper <host>:<port> --describe --topic <topic-name>`

For topics and Consumers use zookeeper port(service) and for consumer use kafka broker.